# Was Already vs Already Was

Tags: word-order

Saw your response to a question about Already Was vs Was Already.

I'm a novice writer.  A beta reader suggested that I edit to Was Already.  The discussion from which I saw your name was a bit vague for me (pardon my inexperience).  Below is the sentence in my novel:

He already was two paces away from her; he started stepping backwards as soon as he scribbled her face.

Hope you can enlighten me.

Comment: *Saw your response to a question about...* Another question here? Then please link to it.

Comment: I did come across the question.  However, responses were varied and contradicting.  This is why I posted the exact sentence I wished clarity on.

Comment: Fine. Still, I repeat, you should refer to that question and explain why that does not answer your issue. You risk getting this question closed as a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

The possible difference in nuance might be

> He **already** was two paces away from her

emphasizes the amount of time passed, where as

> He **was** already two paces away from her

emphasizes the distance between them.

Answer (score 1):

"He already was two paces away from her; he started stepping backwards as soon as he scribbled her face."

I would say that "was already" is the more grammatically correct version.